# Should a senior Program Committee attend the conference?

Tags: conference, program-committee

I would like to know whether a senior Program Committee should attend the conference or not. I mean that physically being there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would write a comment instead of simply giving a downvote. Huh!

Comment: People here make their own choices. A somewhat fuller explanation of your needs here would make down voting less likely. Such short questions often suffer this fate here.

Comment: Your question is unclear. I haven't downvoted but am considering a close vote as "Unclear what you're asking". Try adding a few sentences explaining what you want to know.

Comment: I was just curious to know if a PC should physically be at the conference. I don't know why it is unclear to some of you.

Comment: Your question is unclear on two fronts: What exactly do you mean by "should"? Also, it likely depends on the field.

Comment: I meant physically being there. Let's say it is a CS field. I was expecting at least a simple answer rather than a bunch of critical comments for the question. Anyway. I'll delete it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Should" is a judgement call that I won't make. If you are the person and if you are new at this, I'd recommend that you go.

However, a large and important conference (in CS) might have, say, 30 people on the various committees. At the conference you will likely find about 3/4 of them in attendance. Not everyone, but most. Some will actually be presenters or session chairs.

But the *Capo di tutti capi* would nearly always be there.

Comment: Often the Program Committee will have a meeting or two during the conference to discuss how the current conference is going, and work on the next conference. This should have been made clear when joining the program committee in the first place...